# AS3 Scaling movie clip without scaling children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip that consists of a button and two labels (both flash components). When clicking the button I want to minimize the movie clip by removing one of the labels and then changing the height of the movie clip to only show the button and the first label (both are at the top of the movie).

I have tried changing the height of the movie clip as well as using scaleY but it ends up scaling the label and button along with the movie clip.

Is there a way to only scale the background of the movie without scaling its children (the button and label)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work that way. Scaling the parent affects all children - which is a good thing, because it makes modifying large groups of display objects a whole lot easier.

You will have to change your hierarchy so that the graphics clip you are trying to scale resides on the same level as the labels and the button - just create a new MovieClip and place all four elements (graphics, button, labels) within it.

Comment: The solution I ended up going with was to change the movie clip to have the correct scale on frame 2 and then I can call gotoAndStop(2) to get the desired result

Answer (score 2):

I concur with weltraumpirat that children scaling with parent is a correct behavior.  If you cannot get around with moving them out of the parent, you may consider the following pseudo code which would undo the scaling the parents impact on children:

```
public class ParentClip extends MovieClip
{
    // Consider moving all of those unscalable clips into this MovieClip so you would not have to process them individually
    public var clipsDoNotScale:MovieClip;

    public override function set scaleX(value:Number):void
    {
        var previousValue:Number = super.scaleX;
        super.scaleX = value;

        if ( previousValue != value && clipsDoNotScale )
        {
            clipsDoNotScale.scaleX = 1 / value;

            //Proportionally move the clip too
            clipsDoNotScale.x *= value / previousValue;
        }
    }

    public override function set scaleY(value:Number):void
    {
        var previousValue:Number = super.scaleY;
        super.scaleY = value;

        if ( previousValue != value && clipsDoNotScale )
        {
            clipsDoNotScale.scaleY = 1 / value;

            //Proportionally move the clip too
            clipsDoNotScale.y *= value / previousValue;
        }
    }
}
```